# How does the SNES' Mode 7 sprite perspective projection work?

Tags: sprites, perspective, 2.5d

I've always wanted to know how to replicate the old [Mode 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_7) graphics mode of the Super NES. It was frequently used for a pseudo-3D effect in racing games like [*Top Gear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Gear_(video_game)) ([gameplay video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hru6NR6a_NM)).

[image: Top Gear Bordeaux track]

<sup>*Top Gear* ⓒ Gremlin Graphics. Image credit: [Phil at tasvideos.org](http://tasvideos.org/Game/snes-top-gear.html).</sup>

Every explanation I can find seems a little too complex for me.

In simple terms, how does Mode 7 work?

Comment: A thing to note: Top Gear did not use Mode 7 graphics for the road. Mode 7 graphics cannot produce the curves in the road like this. Note how the roads in Mario Kart on the SNES is a texture that is rotated in perspective (a floor map) while this road can swerve from one side to the other and produce hills and valleys. For info on how this works read this: http://www.extentofthejam.com/pseudo/